# Why a word gets printed?

Tags: java

```
public class printEveryOther{
public static String printEveryOther(String x){
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i = i+2){
        System.out.print (x.charAt(i));
    }
    return x;
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    String x = "method";
    String y = printEveryOther(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

}

When this code runs I want it to produce mto. It prints every other character of a string. However the output for this is mtomethod. Why?

Comment: What did you expect to get when you do `System.out.println(y)`?

Comment: A method with a name like `printEveryOther` implies that it's being called to print something.  Therefore, it should be a `void` method that doesn't return anything--otherwise it's doing two things at once, which is not good coding practice.  If you want a method that **returns** a string with every other character, instead of printing it, change the name--and look into [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an extra print (in other words, `y = "method"`) -

```
public static String printEveryOther(String x){
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i = i+2){
    System.out.print (x.charAt(i));
  }
  return x; // <-- return the input "x" (that is "method")
}

public static void main (String[] args){
  String x = "method";
  String y = printEveryOther(x);
  // System.out.println(y); // <-- y = "method"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `print` in both functions. Your `printEveryOther` function uses `print`, then *the original string is returned* and you `println` that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `System.out.println(y);`...